# AnalyzeSyntax Returns Inaccurate Results for Context

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language, google-cloud-automl-nl

AnalyzeSyntax for "Mary likes to color pictures." returns (as expected) "color" is a verb. But when I do the same test with "Mary colors pictures." The response classifies "colors" is a noun. Unless I am mistaken, in the context of the sentence, "colors" is a verb. Right?

Comment: Currently, customization for 'AnalyzeSyntax' model is yet available, as oppose to customization for text classification, sentiment analysis, and text extraction under AutoML Natural Language.

Comment: I recommend for you to submit a feature request for this on https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers and consider https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/features
for alternatives solutions.

Comment: If you still have other questions, let me know